# Probability: How much days we need to play a game win

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

Suppose the probability of win a lotery game is : $1/1000$

If a person play the lotery every day with the same combination, how much time he need to wait to win the lotery?

Im thinking to use a geometric distribution, but im not really sure if its necessary here.

Comment: The number of days is a random variable.  If you want the distribution then the geometric distribution is the one to go for.

Comment: @Henry I dont know how to apply that distribution in this case, because the number of times the person needs to loose before win for first time is unknown, and that is the number i need.

Comment: @Wyvern666 You're looking for the *expected* number; that is the mean of the distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of independent Bernouli trials until a success is a geometric distributed random variable.

The expected number of trials so required is then the mean of the distribution.

$$N\sim\mathcal{Geo}(1/1000) \implies \mathsf E[N] = \boxed{\qquad?}$$

Do you know what is the mean of a geometric distribution?

Comment: Yes, i know it as "the expected value"... but i dont understand how is that used here. If you go every day to play lotery, then you would say you need to go $E[N]$ days to win?

Comment: @Wyvern666  There are no guarantees. It could take more, or it could take fewer, because it is a random process after all.  But you should expect it to take around the mean amount, by definition.

Comment: Yes, i see it is by definition, but really i don't see it like something intuitive.... Thanks.

Comment: Here's a fun thing about geometric distributions: no matter how many tries you have *already taken and failed*, you shall always expect it to take the same amount of *further* tries until success.

Comment: Oh, that sounds relationed with the Gambler's fallacy.